# Send an email using GWT Java

Tags: java, email, gwt

I have been reviewing the email solutions in stackoverflow and am trying to use the following solution:

```
        EmailTask email = new SimpleEmail();
        //Production
        email.setHostName("mail.hostname.net");
        email.setSmtpPort(25); //No authentication required
        //Test
        //            email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com"); 
        //            email.setSmtpPort(587); //Authentication required
        //            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("me@gmail.com", "mypwd"));

        email.setTLS(true);
        email.setFrom("ATA@hostname.net");
        email.setSubject("New Award Tracking Application account created.");
        email.setMsg("Please set up a new Award Tracking Application account for: " + account);
        email.addTo(to);
        email.send();
        System.out.println("Mail sent!");
```

On the first line (`EmailTask email = new SimpleEmail();`) I get the error

> SimpleEmail cannot be resolved to a type

I have imported  `import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.EmailTask;`  as per the Quick fix when I entered the code. Is there another library I should use?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an Ant task for this? Also, you _are_ doing this on the server-side of your GWT app, right? Remember that all client-side code will be converted to JS. If what you've shown _is_ client-side code, you should create an async method to invoke from the client with the business logic on the server-side.

Comment: Hi @jensgram, no I am not sure that I want to use Ant. I was not sure which library to use and this is the recommended one. From below I should be using "import org.apache.commons.mail.*;". Oh yes, I am doing this on the server-side :-)  Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Commons Email** in your class path https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Check the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) for a simple example.

Class [SimpleEmail](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/SimpleEmail.html)

Comment: Hi @Subodh_Joshi, Thank you I will try this. Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

GWT is a front-end framework, while what you are asking for, sending mails, is a business process.

This link might help you get started: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html

Comment: Why the downvote? This _may_ be spot on, although hard to tell from the question.

Comment: Hi @Stultske, I am not quite sure what you are suggesting here. The code I am using is fairly standard and used by many people. I think all I need is the right library to include. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi @jensgram, Thanks for your support. I am not a programmer and this is a part time project for my Scouts so sometimes it is obvious that I do not know what I really need. However, I muddle along regardless and end up achieving my goal. Regards, Glyn

Comment: @Glyn: do you actually know what you are using? GWT has nothing to do with sending mails. The link I posted is that to the default javamail that is standard in the Java jdk.
If you say that you are "not a programmer", what makes you think it is wise to go for the more difficult solutions? The problem with "muddling along and end up achieving a goal" is that usually this leads to crappy code nobody understands/wants to maintain. I hope this isn't so in your case, but beware anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske, It seems strange that if you can not generate an email from GWT Java that so many people are doing so. They all seem to also need your help and guidance so this post is not a total loss. I shall investigate the information you have so generously provided. I also totally agree with your assessment of my programming skills and is why, as I learn more, I go back to review the code. Unfortunately, I do not have a great deal of time to devote to this. In the meantime I have achieved a significant, even if I do say so myself, contribution to my Scouts by forging ahead.Kind regards

Comment: Actually, nobody tries to generate emails from GWT.What they mean is they have an application in which they use GWT, and from which they want to be able to send mails. It's understanding that difference, that makes looking for helpfull resources a lot easier.